# How to properly handle a native HTML canvas inside a Vue 3 component with Option API

Tags: canvas, vuejs2, vuejs3

here are my code snippet made simple:

```
<template>
    <canvas
        id="imageResizeCanvas"
        ref="imageResizeCanvas"
        style="display:inline"
        width="256px"
        height="256px"
    />

    <img ref="tempImage" />
</template>


mounted () {
    this.canvas = this.$refs.imageResizeCanvas
    this.tempImage = this.$refs.tempImage
}

fileAdded (files) {
   var file = files[0]

   loadImage(file)
      .then((img) => drawImageOnCanvas(img, this.canvas))
      .then((dataURL) => {
          this.tempImage.src = dataURL
      })
    }
  }

  function loadImage (file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = (evt) => {
        let img = new Image()
        img.onload = () => {
          resolve(img)
        }
        img.src = evt.target.result
      }
    })
  }

  function drawImageOnCanvas (img, canvas) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      const calculatedImageProperties = calculateOffSetWidthAndHeight(img, canvas)
      ctx.drawImage(img, calculatedImageProperties.offsetWidth, calculatedImageProperties.offsetHeight, calculatedImageProperties.width, calculatedImageProperties.height)
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL())
    })
  }

  function calculateOffSetWidthAndHeight (img) {
    const CANVAS_SIDE = 256
    var width, height, offsetWidth, offsetHeight

    if (img.height >= img.width) {
        width = CANVAS_SIDE * img.width / img.height
        height = CANVAS_SIDE
    } else {
        width = CANVAS_SIDE
        height = CANVAS_SIDE * img.height / img.width
    }
    offsetWidth = (CANVAS_SIDE - width) > 0 ? (CANVAS_SIDE - width) / 2 : 0
    offsetHeight = (CANVAS_SIDE - height) > 0 ? (256 - height) / 2 : 0

return {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    offsetWidth: offsetWidth,
    offsetHeight: offsetHeight
}
```

}

Basically I select an image from the file system and fire the fildAdded that write in the canvas a little thumbnail. Then I fire the toDataURL to write the resulting url in the tempImage Ref.

With Vue2 was working with no problem, but moving it to Vue3 The toDataURL always return an empty data value.

Can you help me spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the "px" from `width` and `height` of the canvas tag:

```html
<canvas
  width="256"
  height="256"
/>
```

The attributes expect integer input, with the "px" you end up with a non-dimensional canvas and `toDataURL()` will be empty.

When removing the "px", it works in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

async function loadImage (file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  const evt = await new Promise(resolve => reader.onload = resolve)

  const img = new Image()
  img.src = evt.target.result
  await new Promise(resolve => img.onload = resolve)
  return img
}

function drawImageOnCanvas (img, canvas) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight, width, height} = calculateOffSetWidthAndHeight(img)
  ctx.drawImage(img, offsetWidth, offsetHeight, width, height)
  return canvas.toDataURL()
}

function calculateOffSetWidthAndHeight (img) {
  const CANVAS_SIDE = 256
  var width, height, offsetWidth, offsetHeight

  if (img.height >= img.width) {
      width = CANVAS_SIDE * img.width / img.height
      height = CANVAS_SIDE
  } else {
      width = CANVAS_SIDE
      height = CANVAS_SIDE * img.height / img.width
  }
  offsetWidth = (CANVAS_SIDE - width) > 0 ? (CANVAS_SIDE - width) / 2 : 0
  offsetHeight = (CANVAS_SIDE - height) > 0 ? (256 - height) / 2 : 0

  return {width, height, offsetWidth, offsetHeight}
}


const App = { 
  setup() {
    const imageResizeCanvas = ref()
    const tempImage = ref()
    
    async function fileAdded (event) {
      const file = event.target.files?.[0]
      const img = await loadImage(file)
      const dataURL = drawImageOnCanvas(img, imageResizeCanvas.value)
      tempImage.value.src = dataURL
    }
    return {
      imageResizeCanvas, tempImage, fileAdded
    }  
  }
}
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="file" @input="fileAdded">
  </div>
  <canvas
    ref="imageResizeCanvas"
    style="display:inline"
    width="256"
    height="256"
  ></canvas>

  <img ref="tempImage" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```